# java.lang.ClassCastException when trying to reshuffle the buttons

Tags: java, android, exception

Android 2.3.3

I am working on a custom calculator. I am trying the change the UI, just shuffling around the buttons and particularly, i get the ClassCastException when i try to change one button.
I tried "Clean"ing the project, deleting the R.java file, changing the xml file and saving, but none worked. Here is the error stack from eclipse :::

```
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobilevoiceapps.advancedvoicecalculatorplus/com.mobilevoiceapps.advancedvoicecalculatorplus.AdvancedVoiceCalculatorPlus}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at com.mobilevoiceapps.advancedvoicecalculatorplus.AdvancedVoiceCalculatorPlus.onCreate(AdvancedVoiceCalculatorPlus.java:226)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-10 09:19:41.949: E/AndroidRuntime(21494):    ... 11 more
```

Here is the xml file without any errors:::

```
   <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2px"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPower"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="^"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />



                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNthRoot"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="n √x"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />



                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnLog10"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="Log10"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnLN"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="Loge"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

When i change the power button to a different linear layout, the error occurs...

XML when error occurs

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45px"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2px"
                android:background="#000000" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnInverse"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="1/x"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />





                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFactorial"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="n!"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPower"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="^"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPercentage"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="%"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumberLeftBrace"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text="("
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumberRightBrace"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
                    android:text=")"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="24px" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

When i try to change the power(id/btnPower) button, i get the classcastexception. If i replace it in the linearlayout9(id/linearlayout9) then the error disappears. It compiles well, but at runtime, it will give an exception.

```
            btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumber0);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumber1); // line with the error
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumber2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumber3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumber4);
        btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumber5);
        btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNumber6);
```

The error is not at a constant place. It depends on where i insert the power button. I did read quite a few questions on ClassCastException, but i didn't quite understand why is it being caused. I will be glad if someone can explain it in detail.

Please let me know, if you need any other information.

[SOLVED] Uninstall the application from the mobile, go to project->clean and run again. If the error keeps coming, do follow the steps again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try going to Project -> Clean

Comment: As i have already stated, I cleaned the project, but still the exception occurs

Comment: I already had such strange issues. I deleted the app from the phone and recompiled/reinstalled.

Comment: Ok, will uninstall the app, and will try again. Let's see

Comment: @Waza_Be, Thanks for the tip. I got it working. It keeps coming when i try to change other buttons as well, but when i uninstall and recompile the code, it works.

Comment: You can't cast from linearlayout to button...when you want to show that button as a linear layout ..use a LL or View Group ref and assign the view to that casting it to LL or VG as below
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.xxx) or
ViewGroup vg=(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.xxx)

Comment: @manoj, I was not trying to cast anything. I did the usual thing, casting button to button. I have found the answer and updated the question. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already experienced this issue, and lost a lot of time on it, this is just what I did:

- Uninstall the app from phone/emulator
- (clean might help - not sure)
- re-compile and install a fresh version of your app.

A simple clean does not seems to help, the uninstall is more likely to delete strangeness and fix the issue.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the application from the mobile, go to project->clean and run again. If the error keeps coming, do follow the steps again. Thanks for the help.